# How to update a columns having a specific string patter/sequence

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g

There is a column in my table having values of a pattern like `'A=xxx^B=xxx^C=xxx^D=xxx^'` i need to update all the columns having this pattern to a pattern like `'C=xxx^D=xxx^'`, where x is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution since i'm looking for a pattern which starts from `'A='` i used **REGEXP_LIKE** to find that particular pattern. Then i used **SUBSTR** to extract the value from the string which should start from the 2nd `'^'` character.

```
Update MYTABLE t set t.key = SUBSTR(t.key,INSTR(t.key,'^',1,2)+1) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t.key_ref,'^A=') and t.dno = 'xxxxx';
```

Comment: That pattern of yours is far far away from the one you described in the question.

Comment: My bad, What i wanted to say was, By A=xxx there can be a number(could be more than 3 digits). But by xxx it gives the idea of 3 digits. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this help? `REGEXP_LIKE` returns rows which satisfy the condition, while an ordinary `SUBSTR` returns the desired result.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'A=123^B=123^C=123^D=123^'       from dual union
  3     select 'A=123^B=456^C=789^D=987^'       from dual union
  4     select 'A=333^C=333^D=333^'             from dual union
  5     select 'C=987^D=987^'                   from dual union
  6     select 'B=876^'                         from dual union
  7     select 'A=123^B=123^C=123^D=123^E=123^' from dual
  8    )
  9  select col,
 10    substr(col, instr(col, 'C')) result
 11  from test
 12  where regexp_like(col, '^A=\d+{3}\^B=\d+{3}\^C=\d+{3}\^D=\d+{3}\^$');

COL                            RESULT
------------------------------ ------------------------------
A=123^B=123^C=123^D=123^       C=123^D=123^
A=123^B=456^C=789^D=987^       C=789^D=987^

SQL>
```